# How to register a certificate to a port when the cert is in a custom location using netsh

Tags: certificate, store

My certificate is stored in a custom store under "Certificates(Local Computer)" instead of under "Personal".

Normally, if the cert is located under personal, i just use **C:>netsh http add sslcert ipport:0.0.0.0: certhash= appid= certstorename=MY**

where, certstorename=MY is already assumed by default if not specified.

This works fine until we were required to store the certificate in a custom store other than the existing personal, trusted people, trusted publishers, etc. etc.

- If we called our new store "my cert store", how would the new netsh command look like?
- how does the word "MY" map to the "Personal" store? is there a dictionary someplace that maps these?

i checked the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace and there exises an enum called StoreName with the following values:

- AddressBook - The X.509 certificate store for other users.
- AuthRoot - The X.509 certificate store for third-party certificate authorities (CAs).
- CertificateAuthority - The X.509 certificate store for intermediate certificate authorities (CAs).
- Disallowed - The X.509 certificate store for revoked certificates.
- My - The X.509 certificate store for personal certificates.
- Root - The X.509 certificate store for trusted root certificate authorities (CAs).
- TrustedPeople - The X.509 certificate store for directly trusted people and resources.
- TrustedPublisher - The X.509 certificate store for directly trusted publishers.

I tried all of them on the netsh command as certstorename and i always get this error:

**SSL Certificate add failed, Error:1312
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.**

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do seems correct. Could you retry after applying hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981506 for a problem which actually matches your symptoms exactly.

Answer (score 1):

A huge flaw is that even if the **PrivateKey is not persisted** properly, the private key icon will still show up in mmc and it will say "There is a private key associated with this certificate". To know for sure that the private key is being properly imported,

- Right click on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys and take a note of how many files are in the folder (this is where the private keys are kept).
- Import the pfx file / however you are adding the certificate/key to the store
- Check the file count again of that folder, there should be **1 more file** than before

You can try testing this with a newly created, self-signed certificate with a tool like open-ssl. Was stuck on this for weeks until I found this stackoverflow post, [Inserting Certificate (with privatekey) in Root, LocalMachine certificate store fails in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625624/inserting-certificate-with-privatekey-in-root-localmachine-certificate-store)

Another gotcha is to be sure the certificate is in Local Computer (not user), but it looks like you already got that part down.

Answer (score 0):

Open your certificate and double check whether it actually contains a PrivateKey. Depending on how you exported/imported it, it may have been truncated to a public-only data.

In explorer, just double click and check whether "this cert contains private key" warning label is visible on the first tab, just under the expiry dates

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the certificate was installed in my local user store, instead of the *local machine* store. Installing in `localMachine/my` cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

Derrick.  The certstorename just needs quotes.  The AppId is the hardpart.  Remove the EnhancedKeyUsageList part if you made a self-signed cert.  Otherwise prefer to use a cert designed for a server side certificate.

```
$appid = "appid={"+(get-host).InstanceId.guid+"}"
$certhash = ls Cert:\LocalMachine\my | where {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList -Match 'Server' -and $_.subject -match (hostname)}|select -expand Thumbprint -last 1
$cmdline='netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=' + $certhash + ' "' + $appid + '"'
```

*resulting with netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=DD2AA37F947FC61766AF95ADA93DFDC1B171CB8B "appid={723b1673-7ec2-42f2-96c3-e1f5b726feaf}" certstorename="my cert store"*

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 
Invoke-Expression $cmdline


SSL Certificate successfully added
```