# Display X509Certificate with chain elements not in certificate store

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

I have an object of type [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) and want to display it to the user. I'm doing this with the [`X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.displaycertificate.aspx) method.

The problem I have is that this certificate I want to show is **issued by an intermediate CA** whichs certificate is **not in the machines certificate store**, but its root is.

Now if I display said certificate the dialog is **not able to build the chain** *(opposite to me, as I am able to with the [`X509Chain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx) and the intermediate CA as an extra element)*

**How do I display the certificate with the whole chain?**

```
X509Certificate2 endCert = ...;
X509Certificate2 intermediateCA = ...;

X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(intermediateCA);
chain.Build(endCert); // Whole chain!

X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(endCert); // Dialog shows: "The issuer of this certificate could not be found."
```

**(I'm not able/allowed to add the intermediate CA to the user/machine store!)**
**(I'm not able/allowed to create my own dialog. It has to be the default Windows dialog!)**
**(P/Invoke is allowed if required)**

---

*Just as an example you can try these certificates to test above, but you have to reference `System.Security.dll` for `X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate`:*

```
X509Certificate2 endCert = new X509Certificate2(
            Convert.FromBase64String(
                "MIIE8zCCA9ugAwIBAgIQSBDq+mlsLsCZqWMIWj/YADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA8MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMVGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1UaGF3dGUgU1NMIENBMB4XDTExMTI" + 
                "yMDAwMDAwMFoXDTE0MDIxNzIzNTk1OVowgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhNYXJ5bGFuZDEUMBIGA1UEBxQLRm9yZXN0IEhpbGwxIzAhBgNVBAoUGkFwYWNoZSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBGb3VuZGF0aW" +
                "9uMRcwFQYDVQQLFA5JbmZyYXN0cnVjdHVyZTEVMBMGA1UEAxQMKi5hcGFjaGUub3JnMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEApyhxElzdnWks7MMCEx24FMhHCbFcgKbO+fh/+JYrV91Cs" +
                "xsdqsAsvAU37P/eLMQ3ZVm93c6uQbt6cq+0VXniviFjXS3qUUJVUC60Q/YDzaYrTFZdY8ccA5wWdFTiMlJgwIqdlvB7JLkOzotvawRfJxeH+aucY756TdYGapAyno+3pWNXnU5sr1oaJ4uGchaS7LUAqpfP" +
                "fA3oTv63ZmIzHh2MTfDeUgdVSxeqEj3FCObLdps4Fs6c08Re2KAEZ+0UcMwNyJh0y6aP6PBgZAdt3qODONrI56TCDxjMC47lmIrm/U2Vy+v1LB90uU/1ESAiKvIKLjVZucO0U4Ol8VgiSDIH1FezXEhl+fP" + 
                "zY1N18u6kMx0AGDKDO0fBkUpkA6r6K4Kk/YvEJBLiIvLwLLnQhcwJjhRZItA52dNvKHMRYh5er1xVbLj7X+ujDfA6RpJYOmmPUxYzsZpZhTk0wybuGrkuvrm5t9ONP4p/2lan1G9aXqK6OLNh4W9IVUs1o1" +
                "KvMP86ToBOsZY/g50cld0kh7AMR+W/Lg9WtPxs1nq98k2J7HZBmMnYTEqwzSFtsMzGlqcFXO170JnfgklUjzi12vwQYO0bf/q+3e7QQsYRXzSGUEdKJZvzs0P09jJ6W/mDdnMdaoh7eYP5eynleZtElUgcd" +
                "NNgVAHn8NEUnJpwbGUCAwEAAaOBoDCBnTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMDoGA1UdHwQzMDEwL6AtoCuGKWh0dHA6Ly9zdnItb3YtY3JsLnRoYXd0ZS5jb20vVGhhd3RlT1YuY3JsMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUF" +
                "BwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAyBggrBgEFBQcBAQQmMCQwIgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnRoYXd0ZS5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAA6BnlWlsAXvTmDpqijPpBUkD9Xkbys7UC/FOuUVr3P" +
                "K3d3GCQynwhooBe2CAshtxjb3Cc8zJfeqb5IQfjTcuEznIpONvqFvSmU4/INS+3/TPLoyQ81wpsIUbJzhhJY78CH8TZ5cn2BtWkI9fEydAXYe9a64GVdjPBJhneBon3J63s895GSSucQAIQZEiXBAqoklS5" +
                "n0Ud2aSYrNZJUVN3o8Rh0tvd0W2l6KjBaIZLUTieDZb3eRrValvjYDcCp9uI3aTdhht6zxUuE+OZ7DPWIWz3EYTMVTTtQdojJK9mM++JC74Y4s+JSCgRzTn3CxDMWPG5FWxavENub0FfsXfnY="));

X509Certificate2 intermediateCA = new X509Certificate2(
            Convert.FromBase64String(
                "MIIEbDCCA1SgAwIBAgIQTV8sNAiyTCDNbVB+JE3J7DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBqTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMfQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWN" + 
                "lcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIwMDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNVBAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMD" + 
                "AwWhcNMjAwMjA3MjM1OTU5WjA8MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMVGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1UaGF3dGUgU1NMIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmeSFW" + 
                "3ZJfS8F2MWsyMip09yY5tc0pi8M8iIm2KPJFEyPBaRF6BQMWJAFGrfFwQalgK+7HUlrUjSIw1nn72vEJ0GMK2Yd0OCjl5gZNEtB1ZjVxwWtouTX7QytT8G1sCH9PlBTssSQ0NQwZ2ya8Q50xMLciuiX/8mS" + 
                "rgGKVgqYMrAAI+yQGmDD7bs6yw9jnw1EyVLhJZa/7VCViX9WFLG3YR0cB4w6LPf/gN45RdWvGtF42MdxaqMZpzJQIenyDqHGEwNESNFmqFJX1xG0k4vlmZ9d53hR5U32t1m0drUJN00GOBN6HAiYXMRISst" + 
                "SoKn4sZ2Oe3mwIC88lqgRYke7EQIDAQABo4H7MIH4MDIGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCYwJDAiBggrBgEFBQcwAYYWaHR0cDovL29jc3AudGhhd3RlLmNvbTASBgNVHRMBAf8ECDAGAQH/AgEAMDQGA1UdHwQtMCswKa" + 
                "AnoCWGI2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9UaGF3dGVQQ0EuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAoBgNVHREEITAfpB0wGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQVmVyaVNpZ25NUEtJLTItOTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUp6KDuzRFQ" + 
                "D381TBPErk+oQGf9tswHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUe1tFz6/Oy3r9MZIaarbzRutXSFAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAIAigOBsyJUW11cmh/NyNNvGclYnPtOW9i4lkaU+M5enS+Uv+yV9Lwdh+m+DdExMU3Ig" + 
                "pHrPUVFWgYiwbR82LMgrsYiZwf5Eq0hRfNjyRGQq2HGn+xov+RmNNLIjv8RMVR2OROiqXZrdn/0Dx7okQ40tR0Tb9tiYyLL52u/tKVxpEvrRI5YPv5wN8nlFUzeaVi/oVxBw9u6JDEmJmsEj9cIqzEHPIqt" + 
                "lbreUgm0vQF9Y3uuVK6ZyaFIZkSqudZ1OkubK3lTqGKslPOZkpnkfJn1h7X3S5XFV2JMXfBQ4MDzfhuNMrUnjl1nOG5srztxl1Asoa06ERlFE9zMILViXIa4="));
```

---

I am confident that this should be somehow possible, as the Internet Explorer is doing the same. You can try it with *https://httpd.apache.org/ (The certificates above are from there)*
[image]

Comment: Given the way signing works, I think you can construct a new certificate that contains the whole chain.

Comment: @Joshua You mean a signature _(PKCS#7 etc.)_ or a protocol _(SSL/TLS etc.)_ can contain multiple certificates, but a X.509 certificate itself?

Comment: @ordag Are you allowed to create a temporary store ?

Comment: @Yahia Temporary? As long as it is just in memory and it does not affect other applications in any way that would be ok.

Comment: @ordag it would not be in memory BUT it would not affect other applications... is that acceptable ?

Comment: @Yahia And it should not be visible in Certificate Manager etc.

Comment: @Yahia Visibility and separation are important. So, ok, memory is not a must-be. Basically it shall be the same as what IE is doing.

Comment: @ordag it would be visible... then there is NO solution to your question... anyways IF it were really possible THEN it would present a security problem IMHO since the use wouldn't be able to trust the OS dialogue anymore!

Comment: X509 certificates are allowed to contain the chain.

Comment: @Joshua yes, they are allowed but if I understand the question correctly it is about a situation when they do not contain the chain...

Comment: @Joshua Do you know how? Or where?

Comment: @Yahia So IE is an exception and is allowed to do more then other applications? Or does it create a visible store, too?

Comment: @ordag last time I checked IE was much deeper integrated with the OS than any other application - I would not even name IE an application. The only way the official API allows for this is either the method you read in the anser below OR to create a temporary store and copy the whole chain into that store... later on you can just remove that temporary store... BTW: FF has their own dialogue for this stuff...

Comment: @Yahia An own dialog is not an option. Windows Live Mail (ok Microsoft too) can do the same.

Comment: @ordag I can't say that I am all-knowing in this area but from my experience the only two "legal" options (for "normal applications") are the one mentioned in my comment and the one you have answer already... that about what I can provide... perhaps you get lucky and there is someone more knowledgeable/experienced in this area giving you some other answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** this is possible what you are going to need to do is to use CAPI to [create an in memory certificate store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and add your intermediate certs to that and then use the underlying call to [CryptUIDlgViewCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display the dialogue in a way that uses your temporary store.

Answer (score 2):

Found in [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/79f3ab00-e1a9-4b6f-babb-7c232a2cabe3), the example follows your original code:

```
X509Certificate2 endCert = new X509Certificate2(
        Convert.FromBase64String(
            "MIIE8zCCA9ugAwIBAgIQSBDq+mlsLsCZqWMIWj/YADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA8MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMVGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1UaGF3dGUgU1NMIENBMB4XDTExMTI" + 
            "yMDAwMDAwMFoXDTE0MDIxNzIzNTk1OVowgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhNYXJ5bGFuZDEUMBIGA1UEBxQLRm9yZXN0IEhpbGwxIzAhBgNVBAoUGkFwYWNoZSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBGb3VuZGF0aW" +
            "9uMRcwFQYDVQQLFA5JbmZyYXN0cnVjdHVyZTEVMBMGA1UEAxQMKi5hcGFjaGUub3JnMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEApyhxElzdnWks7MMCEx24FMhHCbFcgKbO+fh/+JYrV91Cs" +
            "xsdqsAsvAU37P/eLMQ3ZVm93c6uQbt6cq+0VXniviFjXS3qUUJVUC60Q/YDzaYrTFZdY8ccA5wWdFTiMlJgwIqdlvB7JLkOzotvawRfJxeH+aucY756TdYGapAyno+3pWNXnU5sr1oaJ4uGchaS7LUAqpfP" +
            "fA3oTv63ZmIzHh2MTfDeUgdVSxeqEj3FCObLdps4Fs6c08Re2KAEZ+0UcMwNyJh0y6aP6PBgZAdt3qODONrI56TCDxjMC47lmIrm/U2Vy+v1LB90uU/1ESAiKvIKLjVZucO0U4Ol8VgiSDIH1FezXEhl+fP" + 
            "zY1N18u6kMx0AGDKDO0fBkUpkA6r6K4Kk/YvEJBLiIvLwLLnQhcwJjhRZItA52dNvKHMRYh5er1xVbLj7X+ujDfA6RpJYOmmPUxYzsZpZhTk0wybuGrkuvrm5t9ONP4p/2lan1G9aXqK6OLNh4W9IVUs1o1" +
            "KvMP86ToBOsZY/g50cld0kh7AMR+W/Lg9WtPxs1nq98k2J7HZBmMnYTEqwzSFtsMzGlqcFXO170JnfgklUjzi12vwQYO0bf/q+3e7QQsYRXzSGUEdKJZvzs0P09jJ6W/mDdnMdaoh7eYP5eynleZtElUgcd" +
            "NNgVAHn8NEUnJpwbGUCAwEAAaOBoDCBnTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMDoGA1UdHwQzMDEwL6AtoCuGKWh0dHA6Ly9zdnItb3YtY3JsLnRoYXd0ZS5jb20vVGhhd3RlT1YuY3JsMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUF" +
            "BwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAyBggrBgEFBQcBAQQmMCQwIgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnRoYXd0ZS5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAA6BnlWlsAXvTmDpqijPpBUkD9Xkbys7UC/FOuUVr3P" +
            "K3d3GCQynwhooBe2CAshtxjb3Cc8zJfeqb5IQfjTcuEznIpONvqFvSmU4/INS+3/TPLoyQ81wpsIUbJzhhJY78CH8TZ5cn2BtWkI9fEydAXYe9a64GVdjPBJhneBon3J63s895GSSucQAIQZEiXBAqoklS5" +
            "n0Ud2aSYrNZJUVN3o8Rh0tvd0W2l6KjBaIZLUTieDZb3eRrValvjYDcCp9uI3aTdhht6zxUuE+OZ7DPWIWz3EYTMVTTtQdojJK9mM++JC74Y4s+JSCgRzTn3CxDMWPG5FWxavENub0FfsXfnY="));

        X509Certificate2 intermediateCA = new X509Certificate2(
        Convert.FromBase64String(
            "MIIEbDCCA1SgAwIBAgIQTV8sNAiyTCDNbVB+JE3J7DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBqTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMfQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWN" + 
            "lcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIwMDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNVBAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMD" + 
            "AwWhcNMjAwMjA3MjM1OTU5WjA8MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMVGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1UaGF3dGUgU1NMIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmeSFW" + 
            "3ZJfS8F2MWsyMip09yY5tc0pi8M8iIm2KPJFEyPBaRF6BQMWJAFGrfFwQalgK+7HUlrUjSIw1nn72vEJ0GMK2Yd0OCjl5gZNEtB1ZjVxwWtouTX7QytT8G1sCH9PlBTssSQ0NQwZ2ya8Q50xMLciuiX/8mS" + 
            "rgGKVgqYMrAAI+yQGmDD7bs6yw9jnw1EyVLhJZa/7VCViX9WFLG3YR0cB4w6LPf/gN45RdWvGtF42MdxaqMZpzJQIenyDqHGEwNESNFmqFJX1xG0k4vlmZ9d53hR5U32t1m0drUJN00GOBN6HAiYXMRISst" + 
            "SoKn4sZ2Oe3mwIC88lqgRYke7EQIDAQABo4H7MIH4MDIGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCYwJDAiBggrBgEFBQcwAYYWaHR0cDovL29jc3AudGhhd3RlLmNvbTASBgNVHRMBAf8ECDAGAQH/AgEAMDQGA1UdHwQtMCswKa" + 
            "AnoCWGI2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9UaGF3dGVQQ0EuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAoBgNVHREEITAfpB0wGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQVmVyaVNpZ25NUEtJLTItOTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUp6KDuzRFQ" + 
            "D381TBPErk+oQGf9tswHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUe1tFz6/Oy3r9MZIaarbzRutXSFAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAIAigOBsyJUW11cmh/NyNNvGclYnPtOW9i4lkaU+M5enS+Uv+yV9Lwdh+m+DdExMU3Ig" + 
            "pHrPUVFWgYiwbR82LMgrsYiZwf5Eq0hRfNjyRGQq2HGn+xov+RmNNLIjv8RMVR2OROiqXZrdn/0Dx7okQ40tR0Tb9tiYyLL52u/tKVxpEvrRI5YPv5wN8nlFUzeaVi/oVxBw9u6JDEmJmsEj9cIqzEHPIqt" + 
            "lbreUgm0vQF9Y3uuVK6ZyaFIZkSqudZ1OkubK3lTqGKslPOZkpnkfJn1h7X3S5XFV2JMXfBQ4MDzfhuNMrUnjl1nOG5srztxl1Asoa06ERlFE9zMILViXIa4="));

X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(intermediateCA);
chain.Build(endCert); // Whole chain!

X509Certificate2 fMainCertificate = null;

X509Certificate2Collection fExtraCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();

fMainCertificate = endCert;
fExtraCertificates.Add(intermediateCA);

X509Store lStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

// No need to write to the user's store, just read.
lStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

try
{
    List<X509Certificate2> lAddedCertificates = new List<X509Certificate2>();

    try
{
    foreach (X509Certificate2 lCertificate in fExtraCertificates)

        if (!lStore.Certificates.Contains(lCertificate))
    {
        lStore.Add(lCertificate);

            lAddedCertificates.Add(lCertificate);
        }

        X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(fMainCertificate);
}
    finally
{
    foreach (X509Certificate2 lCertificate in lAddedCertificates)
    lStore.Remove(lCertificate);
}
}
finally { lStore.Close(); }
```

When run, I get the default Windows dialog and the full chain appears to be present:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I get an _"Access denied"_ exception at the `X509Store.Add` method. It seems I am required to open the store with `ReadWrite`. I can not use this solution though, as I am not allowed to touch the users certificate store in any way, even if that is just temporarily. I'm going to add additional information to my question that it should be somehow possible.

Comment: @ordag [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625624/inserting-certificate-with-privatekey-in-root-localmachine-certificate-store) appears to be able to resolve your permission issue. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6455573/517815) specifically on advice for opening the ctor with the right permission mask.

Comment: @MrGomez Thanks but it's not a problem to add a certificate to a store programmatically

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody needs the code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCT
{
    public int dwSize;
    public IntPtr hwndParent;
    public int dwFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String szTitle;
    public IntPtr pCertContext;
    public IntPtr rgszPurposes;
    public int cPurposes;
    public IntPtr pCryptProviderData;
    public Boolean fpCryptProviderDataTrustedUsage;
    public int idxSigner;
    public int idxCert;
    public Boolean fCounterSigner;
    public int idxCounterSigner;
    public int cStores;
    public IntPtr rghStores;
    public int cPropSheetPages;
    public IntPtr rgPropSheetPages;
    public int nStartPage;
}

public static class CryptAPI
{
    public static void ShowCertificateDialog(X509Chain chain, string title, IntPtr parent)
    {
        const int certStoreProvMemory = 2;      // CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY
        const int certCloseStoreCheckFlag = 2;  // CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG
        const uint certStoreAddAlways = 4;      // CERT_STORE_ADD_ALWAYS
        const uint x509AsnEncoding = 1;         // X509_ASN_ENCODING

        var storeHandle = CertOpenStore(certStoreProvMemory, 0, 0, 0, null);
        if (storeHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception();

        try
        {
            foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
            {
                var certificate = element.Certificate;
                var certificateBytes = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
                var certContextHandle = CertCreateCertificateContext(
                    x509AsnEncoding, certificateBytes, (uint)certificateBytes.Length);

                if (certContextHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                CertAddCertificateContextToStore(storeHandle, certContextHandle, certStoreAddAlways, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            var extraStoreArray = new[] { storeHandle };
            var extraStoreArrayHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(extraStoreArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                var extraStorePointer = extraStoreArrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

                var viewInfo = new CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCT();
                viewInfo.hwndParent = parent;
                viewInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(viewInfo);
                viewInfo.pCertContext = chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate.Handle;
                viewInfo.szTitle = title;
                viewInfo.nStartPage = 0;
                viewInfo.cStores = 1;
                viewInfo.rghStores = extraStorePointer;
                var fPropertiesChanged = false;
                CryptUIDlgViewCertificate(ref viewInfo, ref fPropertiesChanged);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (extraStoreArrayHandle.IsAllocated)
                    extraStoreArrayHandle.Free();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CertCloseStore(storeHandle, certCloseStoreCheckFlag);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("CRYPT32", EntryPoint = "CertOpenStore", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CertOpenStore(int storeProvider, int encodingType, int hcryptProv, int flags, string pvPara);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CertCreateCertificateContext([In] uint dwCertEncodingType, [In] byte[] pbCertEncoded, [In] uint cbCertEncoded);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CertAddCertificateContextToStore([In] IntPtr hCertStore, [In] IntPtr pCertContext, [In] uint dwAddDisposition, [In, Out] IntPtr ppStoreContext);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CertFreeCertificateContext([In] IntPtr pCertContext);

    [DllImport("CRYPT32", EntryPoint = "CertCloseStore", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CertCloseStore(IntPtr storeProvider, int flags);

    [DllImport("CryptUI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptUIDlgViewCertificate(ref CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCT pCertViewInfo, ref bool pfPropertiesChanged);
}
```

It takes a certificate chain, where each certificate may not be in user/machine store and shows a dialog with the first certificate in chain. Other certificates are used to build a certificate path.