# Is there a way to get the functionality of command line certreq -accept using C#?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I'm creating a windows form application that imports certificates into the local store - What I want to be able to do is have it pair it with an existing private key when possible.

I know this is possible because I can manually use the certreq -accept command on a certificate and it pairs it just fine.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileName);
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
certStore.Add(certificate);
certStore.Close();
```

Code works great - Just doesn't match it up to a corresponding private key, which I know exists because command line certreq -accept imports it and matches it just fine. If anyone knows how to match that functionality using code ( not running command line in the code ) I'd be grateful for any guidance.

( Side note - Getting the functionality of certutil -repairstore would also be great )

Comment: Does this help at all? Looks like there's some key storage flags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625624/inserting-certificate-with-privatekey-in-root-localmachine-certificate-store

Comment: Don't think so, that looks like when I import a PFX ( public + private key ) which that and similar articles are helpful for.

In this case, I want to import just a public key, and have it recognize that there's an existing private key on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of `certreq -accept` is:

- Open the Request store (e.g. `new X509Store("Request", StoreLocation.LocalMachine)`)
- Find the self-signed certificate which used the same public key as the signed certificate (the cert there was created by certreq)
- Copy the private key to the new certificate (e.g. `var withKey = newCert.CopyWithPrivateKey(requestCert.GetRSAPrivateKey());`)
- Add the `withKey` certificate to the My store (CurrentUser, or LocalMachine, whichever one matched where the key and self-signed cert was)
- Remove `requestCert` from the Request store.

All of which are solvable in C#.  For "same public key" the easiest is to compare the Oid, EncodedKeyValue, and EncodedParameters properties of newCert.PublicKey and requestCert.PublicKey.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to test this out once I get a moment, but that all makes sense.

Comment: Hmm. Any hints on how to see those private keys? I put a watch on the store, created a new CSR, and not seeing them in any store - Do they go somewhere different?

Comment: @StevenHansen if you’re creating the CSR/key via certreq there should be a self-signed cert in a store named “Request” (pretty sure it’s singular). If you’re creating it some other way then whatever that process is dictates where things go...